# Rails css issue after page reload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm not an expert when it comes to rails, my app was working fine but suddenly when i reload any page, at the first milliseconds it shows no compiled css and then everything is fine . 
I don't how to explain it really well but it bugs me every-time i reload the page .

Anyone have encountered this problem or have a fix to it ?

```
app/views/layouts/application.html.erb

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= stylesheet_pack_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  </head>

  <body>
    <%= render 'shared/flash_messages' %>
    <%= render 'shared/navbar' %>
    <main class="container-fluid">
      <%= content_for?(:content) ? yield(:content) : yield %>
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
app/javascript/packs/application.js

require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")
require("stylesheets/application")

import "bootstrap"
```

```
app/javascript/stylesheets/application.scss

$theme-colors: (

  "primary": #4299E1,

  // Gray colors
  "gray-100": #F7FAFC,
  "gray-200": #EDF2F7,
  "gray-300": #E2E8F0,
  "gray-400": #CBD5E0,
  "gray-500": #A0AEC0,
  "gray-600": #718096,
  "gray-700": #4A5568,
  "gray-800": #2D3748,
  "gray-900": #1A202C,

  // Blue Colors
  "blue-100": #EBF8FF,
  "blue-200": #BEE3F8,
  "blue-300": #90CDF4,
  "blue-400": #63B3ED,
  "blue-500": #4299E1,
  "blue-600": #3182CE,
  "blue-700": #2B6CB0,
  "blue-800": #2C5282,
  "blue-900": #2A4365,

  // Red colors
  "red-100": #FDEEEE,
  "red-200": #FAD4D5,
  "red-300": #F7B9BB,
  "red-400": #F28589,
  "red-500": #EC5156,
  "red-600": #D4494D,
  "red-700": #8E3134,
  "red-800": #6A2427,
  "red-900": #47181A,

  // Green colors
  "green-100": #EFF9F4,
  "green-200": #D7F1E4,
  "green-300": #BEE9D4,
  "green-400": #8ED8B3,
  "green-500": #5DC793,
  "green-600": #54B384,
  "green-700": #387758,
  "green-800": #2A5A42,
  "green-900": #1C3C2C,

);

@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
```

Comment: I can suggest only one - you are loading CSS not in a header of a page.

Comment: You are asking a very vague question. Broad and vague questions tend to get closed. I recommend reading the help center topics on [asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). In this case, I think it would help if you showed an example of your views so we can see where your CSS is loaded.

Comment: Sorry!, i'm just new in stack community and there's a lot for me to learn. this is my default setup with bootstrap using webpacker, i'm not sure if there's any other files i should include .

Comment: This is known as [flash of unstyled content](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content) for what it's worth

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what's happening. is there any rails configuration i could resolve this situation ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with webpacker i was using bootstrap with webpacker, instead i have switch to the [bootstrap-rubygem](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-rubygem) and it's working well .